# I don't understand how to interpret "Events/MeV" in plots like this

Tags: neutrinos, statistics, data-analysis

I was reading a paper regarding electron excess events in MiniBooNE data and I came across the following plot:[image: source: 10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.231801]

I don't understand how to interpret the meaning of "events/MeV". This is a histogram and there are specific bin widths. So, is "events/MeV" the total number of events in a given interval/the bin width? or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label indicates the binning of the histogram. In this case, "Events / MeV" implies that the histograms are constructed using 1 MeV bin widths. Bin contents correspond, accordingly, to the number of events in the bin divided by the bin width (so, yes, your guess is correct).

Answer (score 1):

(This should be a comment, but they tend to delete comments that contain an answer).

It is the number of events whose  Energy value falls within the 1 MeV bin at that particular Energy on the x axis, Energy/mev on the Y axis.